# How do I transform a torch with size (1,3,512,512) to a (1,4,512,512)?

Tags: python, pytorch

I know that it's very easy to make a transformation to a torch in the first and last second ones parameters by adding terms but my problem is with the second parameter I know it probably need to create matrices but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Give the proper usecase and description

Answer (score 0):

Trying to figure out what you are asking.

Let's say you have a batch of one color image of size 2x2 (which is easier to print out than a 512x512):

```
import torch
tensor = torch.rand(1, 3, 2, 2)
```

And you want to add a new channel (already as a batch avoiding to [unsqueeze](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html)):

```
new_ch = torch.ones(1, 1, 2, 2)
```

Then you can use [torch.cat](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html#torch-cat) and concatenate the tensors.

Adding the new channel as first channel:

```
res1 = torch.cat((new_ch, tensor), 1)

# tensor([[[[1.0000, 1.0000],
#           [1.0000, 1.0000]],
#
#          [[0.7760, 0.8937],
#           [0.8792, 0.7196]],
#
#          [[0.0572, 0.7301],
#           [0.4773, 0.2978]],
#
#          [[0.7117, 0.9146],
#           [0.8649, 0.8045]]]])
```

Adding it as last channel:

```
res2 = torch.cat((tensor, new_ch), 1)
# tensor([[[[0.9874, 0.5233],
#           [0.7427, 0.7670]],
#
#          [[0.1921, 0.0732],
#           [0.5393, 0.8496]],
#
#          [[0.7740, 0.5176],
#           [0.7572, 0.0050]],
#
#          [[1.0000, 1.0000],
#           [1.0000, 1.0000]]]])
```

Adding in between:

```
ch_id = 1 # from 0 to 3 (0 as first, 3 as last)
res3 = torch.cat((tensor[:,:ch_id,:,:], new_ch, tensor[:,ch_id:,:,:]), 1)

# tensor([[[[0.9874, 0.5233],
#           [0.7427, 0.7670]],
#
#          [[1.0000, 1.0000],
#           [1.0000, 1.0000]],
#
#          [[0.1921, 0.0732],
#           [0.5393, 0.8496]],
#
#          [[0.7740, 0.5176],
#           [0.7572, 0.0050]]]])
```